How to change localhost to local ip for a .NET 7 web application?
I've built a small web application using .NET 7. It works fine locally with https://127.0.0.1:1234 or https://localhost:1234.
It uses the GET/POST API calls to get data from other computers and send to a database. So I want it able to be connect by other devices in the same network. When i change it with my real local IP, like https://192.168.1.1:9111, it doesn't work anymore. I'm getting

Error: socket hang up

from Postman.
Here is my code. Did I miss anything?
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
app.Run("https://192.168.1.1:9111");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}


Use 0.0.0.0 to bind to all local interfaces. You might have to open a firewall port

@Panagiotis Kanavos 192.168.1.1 is the IP from router. I want to use it instead of localhost so other devices in the same network can access this application

.NET 7 is out of support already - don't use it for new stuff anymore, switch to .NET 8

Hi. I Use only app.run() without Ip. Also check is your computer firewall is opened for port 9111

works fine locally with https://127.0.0.1:1234 or https://localhost:1234  https://192.168.1.1:9111, it doesn't work anymore --> when we test in the local machine, it's not related to firewall, but if we want to access it in other device, then we must make sure firewall is opened. By the way, I had a test in my side with your code app.Run("https://192.168.1.1:9111"); which worked for me to hit a Get request through the browser via the https://192.168.1.1:9111/endpoint. So that I'm afraid you might test it in another device?

By the way, we might configure the launchsettings.json -> profiles ->https -> "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000" instead of the default https://localhost. So that we only need to use app.run(). Then make sure https://192.168.1.1:5001 worked in local machine, then try to visit it in other devices. If it worked locally but not in other devices, then let's troubleshoot a network issue. For example your company has some policies to refuse similar connections.

this is my test result with Kestrel https://i.sstatic.net/FlnZ9EVo.png

@Tiny Wang WOW thx! That configure part helped a lot!

You need to specify which endpoints your API should listen on.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:9111", "http://127.0.0.1:9111", "http://192.168.1.1:9111");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
var app = builder.Build();

// Rest of your code
// You do not need the `app.Run...` part


If you want able to be connect by other devices, You need to install IIS on your computer or any other server technology and just run
app.Run();


"You need to install IIS on your computer or any other server technology " -  no, it is not required.

but I just try and it didn't work on my pc this code builder.WebHost.UseUrls. May be it's my bad idk
